# How to calculate year-on-year data for weekly data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Taking the ***Weekly Economic Index (Lewis-Mertens-Stock)*** data in the link as an example (click the ***download*** button on [this page](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/WEI) to download), I hope to calculate the year-on-year weekly data, but there aren't exactly 52 weeks in a year.

The main problem here is that some years mostly have 52 weeks, while for example, 2015 and 2020 have 53 weeks. I hope to calculate the year-on-year data for the 53rd week of 2015 and 2020 with the 52nd week of 2014 and 2019, so as to deal with the problem of inconsistency between weeks in these two years.

How can I write a weekly year-on-year calculation function to calculate the year-on-year comparison between the year with data for the 53rd week and the 52nd week of the previous year? Of course, if there are other ways to calculate the weekly year-over-year calculation, suggestions are also welcome. Thanks.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('../raw_data/WEI.xls', skiprows=10)
df['observation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['observation_date'])
df

def add_date_parts(df, date_column):
     # df['year_week_ori'] = df[date_column].dt.strftime('%Y-%U')
     df['year_week_ori'] = df[date_column].dt.strftime('%Y-%V')
     df['year'] = df[date_column].dt.isocalendar().year
     df['week'] = df[date_column].dt.isocalendar().week
     # df['year_week_ori'] = df['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['week'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
     df.loc[df['week'] > 52, 'week'] = 52
     df['year_week_modified'] = df['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['week'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
     df['year'] = df[date_column].dt.year
     df['month'] = df[date_column].dt.month
     return df
df = add_date_parts(df, 'observation_date')
df
```

Out:

```
    observation_date   WEI year_week_ori  year  week year_week_modified  month
0         2008-01-05  1.80       2008-01  2008     1            2008-01      1
1         2008-01-12  1.78       2008-02  2008     2            2008-02      1
2         2008-01-19  1.75       2008-03  2008     3            2008-03      1
3         2008-01-26  1.28       2008-04  2008     4            2008-04      1
4         2008-02-02  0.99       2008-05  2008     5            2008-05      2
..               ...   ...           ...   ...   ...                ...    ...
817       2023-09-02  1.72       2023-35  2023    35            2023-35      9
818       2023-09-09  1.72       2023-36  2023    36            2023-36      9
819       2023-09-16  2.17       2023-37  2023    37            2023-37      9
820       2023-09-23  1.62       2023-38  2023    38            2023-38      9
821       2023-09-30  1.83       2023-39  2023    39            2023-39      9
[822 rows x 7 columns]
```

By checking the week quantities of each year, we can see that in the years 2011, 2016, and 2022, we have data for 53 weeks:

```
df.groupby('year')['WEI'].count()
Out[61]: 
year
2008    52
2009    52
2010    52
2011    53
2012    52
2013    52
2014    52
2015    52
2016    53
2017    52
2018    52
2019    52
2020    52
2021    52
2022    53
2023    39
```

My function (it is not yet compatible with the problem that weekly quantities in consecutive years cannot be aligned):

```
def calculate_week_on_week(df, value_column, date_column):
    df = df.sort_values(date_column)
    df['value_last_year'] = df[value_column].shift(52)
    df['week_on_week'] = (df[value_column] - df['value_last_year'])/df['value_last_year']
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

To solve problem, we need [a minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your example, I deleted unnecessary columns and created a world that exists until the 2nd week.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'date': ['2008-01-05', '2008-01-12', '2009-01-03', '2009-01-10', '2009-01-17'], 
        'WEI': [10, 20, 18, 14, 16], 
        'year': [2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009], 'week': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df

```
    date        WEI year    week
0   2008-01-05  10  2008    1
1   2008-01-12  20  2008    2
2   2009-01-03  18  2009    1
3   2009-01-10  14  2009    2
4   2009-01-17  16  2009    3
```

**Code**

Most years end with 2 weeks (like 2008), but 3 years end with three weeks (like 2009). Return the year-over-year change rate, but compare 3rd week of 2009 with the 2nd week of 2008.

```
n = 3
s1 = df.groupby('week')['WEI'].pct_change()
cond = df['week'] == n
s1.mask(cond, df['WEI'].pct_change(n))
```

output:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    0.8
3   -0.3
4   -0.2
```

For the first and second weeks, the data was grouped by week and compared to the corresponding weeks of the previous year. For the third week, the change rate was calculated by comparing to the value three rows above.

now make output to `change` column

```
df.assign(change=s1.mask(cond, df['WEI'].pct_change(n)))
```

output:

```
    date        WEI year    week    change
0   2008-01-05  10  2008    1       NaN
1   2008-01-12  20  2008    2       NaN
2   2009-01-03  18  2009    1       0.8    <- compare with 10
3   2009-01-10  14  2009    2       -0.3   <- compare with 20
4   2009-01-17  16  2009    3       -0.2   <- compare with 20
```

When applying to your dataset, replace n with 53 to match your example.

Comment: Sorry, I have one question, is this solution suitable for the year of 2023, which have 39 entries?

Comment: @ahbon Of course. Generate a sample of only the first week of 2010 and add it to the example to check.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a simpler approach. Rather than try to match weeks between years, calculate the percentage change on a 52 week lag rather than a 1 year lag. This will be 7 * 52 = 364 days, which is only wrong by one day, or two days in a leap year.

First, since WEI is on FRED, you can use [Pandas Datareader](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to load it.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime (2008, 1, 1)
wei_series = pdr.get_data_fred('WEI', start)
```

Next, you can use the periods argument to [`pct_change()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html), which changes the number of periods to look back to calculate the change.

```
wei_series_pct = wei_series.pct_change(52).dropna() * 100
print(wei_series_pct)
```

And that's it.

Side note: since the dataset you're using crosses zero, calculating percent change gets a little strange.

[image: percent change plot on 52 week lag]

That's a 12,000% percent increase between 2021-02-27, and 2022-02-26, which happens because WEI rises from 0.04 to 4.96 over that period.

Comment: Thanks. What you said makes sense. Maybe the fluctuation or error caused by the offset of one or two days is not as big as I thought. If it's large, maybe I should try a 3-week or 4-week moving average and calculate year-over-year.